# What is the correct way to test a contract that depends on another contract?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, truffle

Test Code:

```
let pim = await PassiveIncomeMethod.new(
        u.admin.address,
        "Test Method",
        sf.host.address,
        sf.agreements.cfa.address,
        daix.address
    );

    app = await Proposal.new(
        "Test project",
        "Test description.",
        1000000,
        10000,
        pim.address,
        3600 * 3 // deadline of 3 days in seconds
    );
```

I am using truffle to try and test a contract "Proposal" that needs the address of another contract "PassiveIncomeMethod". I'm trying to create a PassiveIncomeMethod contract and then hand off the address to Proposal but I'm unsure of how to correctly pass the address. I'm currently getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')
at appStatus (test/Proposal.test.js:137:49)
at Context.<anonymous> (test/Proposal.test.js:168:19)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Edit: I added a console.log(pim) below for reference. Some values shortened for readability. Also it's not very readable. It's huge. Sorry.

```
TruffleContract {
  constructor: [Function: TruffleContract] {
    _constructorMethods: {
      configureNetwork: [Function: configureNetwork],
      setProvider: [Function: setProvider],
      new: [Function: new],
      at: [AsyncFunction: at],
      deployed: [AsyncFunction: deployed],
      defaults: [Function: defaults],
      hasNetwork: [Function: hasNetwork],
      isDeployed: [Function: isDeployed],
      detectNetwork: [AsyncFunction: detectNetwork],
      setNetwork: [Function: setNetwork],
      setNetworkType: [Function: setNetworkType],
      setWallet: [Function: setWallet],
      resetAddress: [Function: resetAddress],
      link: [Function: link],
      clone: [Function: clone],
      addProp: [Function: addProp],
      toJSON: [Function: toJSON],
      decodeLogs: [Function: decodeLogs]
    },
    _properties: {
      contract_name: [Object],
      contractName: [Object],
      gasMultiplier: [Object],
      timeoutBlocks: [Object],
      autoGas: [Object],
      numberFormat: [Object],
      abi: [Object],
      metadata: [Function: metadata],
      network: [Function: network],
      networks: [Function: networks],
      address: [Object],
      transactionHash: [Object],
      links: [Function: links],
      events: [Function: events],
      binary: [Function: binary],
      deployedBinary: [Function: deployedBinary],
      unlinked_binary: [Object],
      bytecode: [Object],
      deployedBytecode: [Object],
      sourceMap: [Object],
      deployedSourceMap: [Object],
      source: [Object],
      sourcePath: [Object],
      legacyAST: [Object],
      ast: [Object],
      compiler: [Object],
      schema_version: [Function: schema_version],
      schemaVersion: [Function: schemaVersion],
      updated_at: [Function: updated_at],
      updatedAt: [Function: updatedAt],
      userdoc: [Function: userdoc],
      devdoc: [Function: devdoc],
      networkType: [Object],
      immutableReferences: [Object],
      generatedSources: [Object],
      deployedGeneratedSources: [Object],
      db: [Object]
    },
    _property_values: {},
    _json: {
      contractName: 'PassiveIncomeMethod',
      abi: [Array],
      metadata: '{"compiler":{"version":"0.7.6+commit.7338295f"},"language":"Solidity","output":{"abi":[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_methodName","type":"string"},{"internalType":"contract ISuperfluid","name":"host","type":"address"},{"internalType":"contract IConstantFlowAgreementV1","name":"cfa","type":"address"},{"internalType":"contract ISuperToken","name":"acceptedToken","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"receiver","type":"address"}],"name":"ReceiverChanged","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract ISuperToken","name":"_superToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_agreementClass","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_ctx","type":"bytes"}],"name":"afterAgreementCreated","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"newCtx","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract ISuperToken","name":"_superToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_agreementClass","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_ctx","type":"bytes"}],"name":"afterAgreementTerminated","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"newCtx","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract ISuperToken","name":"_superToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_agreementClass","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"agreementData","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_ctx","type":"bytes"}],"name":"afterAgreementUpdated","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"newCtx","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract ISuperToken","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"beforeAgreementCreated","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract ISuperToken","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"beforeAgreementTerminated","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract ISuperToken","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"beforeAgreementUpdated","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"currentReceiver","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"startTime","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"receiver","type":"address"},{"internalType":"int96","name":"flowRate","type":"int96"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"methodName","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}],"devdoc":{"kind":"dev","methods":{},"version":1},"userdoc":{"kind":"user","methods":{},"version":1}},"settings":{"compilationTarget":{"project:/contracts/PassiveIncomeMethod.sol":"PassiveIncomeMethod"},"evmVersion":"istanbul","libraries":{},"metadata":{"bytecodeHash":"ipfs"},"optimizer":{"enabled":false,"runs":200},"remappings":[]},"sources":{"@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol":{"keccak256":"0x5f02220344881ce43204ae4a6281145a67bc52c2bb1290a791857df3d19d78f5","license":"MIT","urls":["bzz-raw://24427744bd3e6cb73c17010119af12a318289c0253a4d9acb8576c9fb3797b08","dweb:/ipfs/QmTLDqpKRBuxGxRAmjgXt9AkXyACW3MtKzi7PYjm5iMfGC"]},"@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC777/IERC777.sol":{"keccak256":"0xe81b5fca616ec6f57bb9d1ab0750202b9e514760462274ac04495e8c249697ab","license":"MIT","urls":["bzz-raw://1e23a53ea7f3787f90ff8f6e25ea47896ed4b56e336e72ae543e3ef74eaa9e23","dweb:/ipfs/QmSDNkjN5k2VRbrfWdTMJ39dzcSvFz4YMQqHZ5z61qLNVA"]},"@superfluid-finance/ethereum-contracts/contracts/apps/SuperAppBase.sol":{"keccak256":"0x76db1497b95aa8af5c6b6d64222c5894c6f5e5662844b7287f0134cbbd0bb5c5","license":"AGPLv3","urls":["bzz-raw://d4a6716fa1bfbdc04a2b2481eb742691ac29b588118972cf81fdea8519a19ece","dweb:/ipfs/QmRpAuUqUdyihVYKBAcGqxeVEbF14URT9oQJYAc4wdkSX6"]},"@superfluid-finance/ethereum-contracts/contracts/interfaces/agreements/IConstantFlowAgreementV1.sol":{"keccak256":"0xc47783262893c4600d412987ea47558b3b79336407462e6dff2117c04304177f","license":"AGPLv3","urls":["bzz-raw://ad36bacfb037ac85431f8a48f0c5a8d011d506a32c99ee3f3d0df23183dff024","dweb:/ipfs/QmZqEon9aSVLcJ6QdB2oVA9SfhCz4E1h7q2CbRSxhvwp9x"]},"@superfluid-finance/ethereum-contracts/contracts/interfaces/superfluid/Definitions.sol":{"keccak256":"0x81b19f6e00ad3aabb670f75ae7fb4fac8b7e03fb70cc94a81b9c43ce6e2fea96","license":"AGPLv3","urls":["bzz-raw://350c878a85cc34dd0c7a0498da665124521de981e01fa7e1cee0198f6954024b","dweb:/ipfs/QmaM3rD9UoxF3zNt2v2NG5KSQrqBQYRPck3ytYzycKi2oy"]},"@superfluid-finance/ethereum-contracts/contracts/interfaces/superfluid/ISuperAgreement.sol":{"keccak256":"0xcf8a33fadd5db47562156a11098623246efd1b46a2c3d28269767bcbb324fd66","license":"AGPLv3","urls":["bzz-raw://5c0273b4a136874ca4ad1b3f66b312adfa8e8ed48b301e4e979081d4923bb55f","dweb:/ipfs/QmQvK9ZQggymJAftai2aA89EfQY2hX3MSpejNkr6kNf45m"]},"@superfluid-finance/ethereum-contracts/contracts/interfaces/superfluid/ISuperApp.sol":{"keccak256":"0xca93702505ec3c8244227e372687d9bdbc9d368fa07723d310ab9550501abb2a","license":"AGPLv3","urls":["bzz-raw://3514c2c72fc866064227ea28fceea9dec4ca27cdbda2cff546b59f6b899cee4d","dweb:/ipfs/QmdpFCRDm8An2U6TCTUK3Zopp8wVS44mzh2YjVvtruE3dZ"]},"@superfluid-finance/ethereum-contracts/contracts/interfaces/superfluid/ISuperToken.sol":{"keccak256":"0xba355f7d7d5d32ca345bcdb355759ba598a911ff07227ff80012a5e0bf660fb1","license":"AGPLv3","urls":["bzz-raw://72c2669590a012587b892f0bbb166079ffb9e4c2044511b45eb6b34489f83b30","dweb:/ipfs/QmQckdZ7tbboxPpXSt8irWo98KBcZRT5xNPuGf7yuZxZw2"]},"@superfluid-finance/ethereum-contracts/contracts/interfaces/superfluid/ISuperTokenFactory.sol":{"keccak256":"0x7dc514c6c9eda681ed8ad66ccfb68dc22764b6c429ab55fddbba28b6b148621b","license":"AGPLv3","urls":["bzz-raw://bc4b3b35bb0ddd9323afa1f25468eb706e5f7eccce6ff9beec9657aeea8bec33","dweb:/ipfs/QmSLKq8JYWavnjDokYoe1cUERbvWFfiBWBJ2zDCMVyycsM"]},"@superfluid-finance/ethereum-contracts/contracts/interfaces/superfluid/ISuperfluid.sol":{"keccak256":"0x130e01e2fdb535e4a512afd4a62c618d1bc162d3ba17ebaa71ece8b1679ffbc7","license":"AGPLv3","urls":["bzz-raw://af21737d0cc497ddd0a30500f2932f9686a45b956028c340e38bbcfe39f9ab3a","dweb:/ipfs/QmYstcU8VDf7yXtNF5wGaDenwXAejHRj2n4yNRUzzUfhmG"]},"@superfluid-finance/ethereum-contracts/contracts/interfaces/superfluid/ISuperfluidGovernance.sol":{"keccak256":"0x1494ca0fcbe19dac4d2cf599dacd1053c1405d96965761f4bbae9fc4f39e88ac","license":"AGPLv3","urls":["bzz-raw://c9331c83987de6df504b8944efbc312fb8de474b16c191acc135c2a5a4666583","dweb:/ipfs/QmfBbxJBd3bXYZ7Ue8hJds2Sbytzkc4R68dVcbUB2e8PTB"]},"@superfluid-finance/ethereum-contracts/contracts/interfaces/superfluid/ISuperfluidToken.sol":{"keccak256":"0xc658bc41894eecb8f64de68b92011c66b9ae2ec4d0373321c3f558a527f8ecc4","license":"AGPLv3","urls":["bzz-raw://5b107e8e8a6a87113cfb238b7a79efaf755af66188599aa71bc1d58799098894","dweb:/ipfs/Qme1TxqHKLVsKwbrcjA7632VfUkDvbCBzZQyWGm8sRgwRk"]},"@superfluid-finance/ethereum-contracts/contracts/interfaces/tokens/ERC20WithTokenInfo.sol":{"keccak256":"0x808d3a486826e7f119671174a77896c6e23578e691625350dbb3e9f74a0d5137","license":"AGPLv3","urls":["bzz-raw://06a7a1bc2ed6888c7080a8e1fb676b7f3972b3f22620c771a41ca3a0ee78b968","dweb:/ipfs/QmW7qpRwv2vEtCtENoP4BUkK4yRBbiKUZbPbyXNbPthiLQ"]},"@superfluid-finance/ethereum-contracts/contracts/interfaces/tokens/TokenInfo.sol":{"keccak256":"0x4dee21b8f64edbfe811a300d31f529b5367d1186d69b8b2b8dc3373be7a108b0","license":"AGPLv3","urls":["bzz-raw://67edf7ddbd90cd7871dc3c92202d4a749d3be0065174fd0f5b89b18edac9d8d1","dweb:/ipfs/QmNc58Ep6sYkSybGVAgmkeCjHFdBL2m1sGJGUgR99xKqeh"]},"project:/contracts/PassiveIncomeMethod.sol":{"keccak256":"0x8f07a2c9051de9f0fb64e18a79931e0238894cb68a4843b85f9f48aa89a005b9","license":"MIT","urls":["bzz-raw://71f59e21aa0f8e5c4414c532a48904cdfbe58beda51c05dafce1a61e766a275a","dweb:/ipfs/QmQUfdDUdPqNJUYvQusCtP7AYT2NUphaXtFwdw8XzwUTyC"]},"project:/contracts/RedirectAll.sol":{"keccak256":"0xed57ca110caf07bb7da8d9b9d88f474ac66ad287c8b7fc5ac03e59ac9a7a90ad","license":"MIT","urls":["bzz-raw://e00957b094e1ce448df90655f51954178b6a5660476f05b2d3b57731c35f7b6b","dweb:/ipfs/QmSVdidWixj5ZJcaV9W54bYkuPkBr1DJP5GVdhBUFedehK"]}},"version":1}',
      bytecode: '0x608060405234801562000011576000...',
      deployedBytecode: '0x608060405234801561001057600...',
      immutableReferences: {},
      generatedSources: [Array],
      deployedGeneratedSources: [Array],
      sourceMap: '160:421:28:-:0;;;240:339;;;;;;;;;;...',
      deployedSourceMap: '160:421:28:-:0;;;;;;;;;;;;...',
      source: '//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT\n' +
        'pragma solidity ^0.7.1;\n' +
        '    \n' +
        'import {RedirectAll, ISuperToken, IConstantFlowAgreementV1, ISuperfluid} from "./RedirectAll.sol";\n' +
        '\n' +
        'contract PassiveIncomeMethod is RedirectAll{\n' +
        '    string public methodName;\n' +
        '\n' +
        '    constructor(\n' +
        '        address owner,\n' +
        '        string memory _methodName,\n' +
        '        ISuperfluid host,\n' +
        '        IConstantFlowAgreementV1 cfa,\n' +
        '        ISuperToken acceptedToken\n' +
        '    ) \n' +
        '        RedirectAll (\n' +
        '            host,\n' +
        '            cfa,\n' +
        '            acceptedToken,\n' +
        '            owner\n' +
        '        ) \n' +
        '         {\n' +
        '        methodName = _methodName;\n' +
        '    }\n' +
        '}',
      sourcePath: '/mnt/c/Users/dylan/projects/demos/community_dao_prototype/contracts/PassiveIncomeMethod.sol',
      ast: [Object],
      legacyAST: [Object],
      compiler: [Object],
      networks: {},
      schemaVersion: '3.4.3',
      updatedAt: '2021-12-01T05:23:22.053Z',
      networkType: 'ethereum',
      devdoc: [Object],
      userdoc: [Object],
      db: undefined,
      autoGas: true,
      gasMultiplier: 1.25
    },
    configureNetwork: [Function: bound configureNetwork],
    setProvider: [Function: bound setProvider],
    new: [Function: bound new] {
      estimateGas: [Function: bound estimateDeployment],
      request: [Function: bound requestDeployment]
    },
    at: [Function: bound at] AsyncFunction,
    deployed: [Function: bound deployed] AsyncFunction,
    defaults: [Function: bound defaults],
    hasNetwork: [Function: bound hasNetwork],
    isDeployed: [Function: bound isDeployed],
    detectNetwork: [Function: bound detectNetwork] AsyncFunction,
    setNetwork: [Function: bound setNetwork],
    setNetworkType: [Function: bound setNetworkType],
    setWallet: [Function: bound setWallet],
    resetAddress: [Function: bound resetAddress],
    link: [Function: bound link],
    clone: [Function: bound clone],
    addProp: [Function: bound addProp],
    toJSON: [Function: bound toJSON],
    decodeLogs: [Function: bound decodeLogs],
    enums: {},
    class_defaults: { from: '0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57' },
    interfaceAdapter: Web3InterfaceAdapter { web3: [Web3Shim] },
    web3: Web3Shim {
      currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
      _requestManager: [RequestManager],
      givenProvider: null,
      providers: [Object],
      _provider: [HttpProvider],
      setProvider: [Function (anonymous)],
      setRequestManager: [Function (anonymous)],
      BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
      extend: [Function],
      version: '1.5.3',
      utils: [Object],
      eth: [Eth],
      shh: [Shh],
      bzz: [Bzz],
      networkType: 'ethereum'
    },
    currentProvider: HttpProvider {
      withCredentials: false,
      timeout: 0,
      headers: undefined,
      agent: undefined,
      connected: true,
      host: 'http://127.0.0.1:37293/',
      httpAgent: [Agent],
      send: [Function (anonymous)],
      _alreadyWrapped: true
    },
    network_id: '4447',
    disableConfirmationListener: undefined,
    ens: { enabled: false, registryAddress: null },
    reloadJson: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  methods: {
    'afterAgreementCreated(address,address,bytes32,bytes,bytes,bytes)': [Function (anonymous)] {
      call: [Function (anonymous)],
      sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
      estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
      request: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    'afterAgreementTerminated(address,address,bytes32,bytes,bytes,bytes)': [Function (anonymous)] {
      call: [Function (anonymous)],
      sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
      estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
      request: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    'afterAgreementUpdated(address,address,bytes32,bytes,bytes,bytes)': [Function (anonymous)] {
      call: [Function (anonymous)],
      sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
      estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
      request: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    'beforeAgreementCreated(address,address,bytes32,bytes,bytes)': [Function (anonymous)] {
      call: [Function (anonymous)],
      sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
      estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
      request: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    'beforeAgreementTerminated(address,address,bytes32,bytes,bytes)': [Function (anonymous)] {
      call: [Function (anonymous)],
      sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
      estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
      request: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    'beforeAgreementUpdated(address,address,bytes32,bytes,bytes)': [Function (anonymous)] {
      call: [Function (anonymous)],
      sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
      estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
      request: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    'currentReceiver()': [Function (anonymous)] {
      call: [Function (anonymous)],
      sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
      estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
      request: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    'methodName()': [Function (anonymous)] {
      call: [Function (anonymous)],
      sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
      estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
      request: [Function (anonymous)]
    }
  },
  abi: [
    {
      inputs: [Array],
      stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
      type: 'constructor',
      constant: undefined,
      payable: undefined,
      signature: 'constructor'
    },
    {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [Array],
      name: 'ReceiverChanged',
      type: 'event',
      constant: undefined,
      payable: undefined,
      signature: '0x7dfb1d59db37a3fd2e15e796c189dcab714cdbb18650d68a1de58f8fa60718c9'
    },
    {
      inputs: [Array],
      name: 'afterAgreementCreated',
      outputs: [Array],
      stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
      type: 'function',
      constant: undefined,
      payable: undefined,
      signature: '0xd86ed3e5'
    },
    {
      inputs: [Array],
      name: 'afterAgreementTerminated',
      outputs: [Array],
      stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
      type: 'function',
      constant: undefined,
      payable: undefined,
      signature: '0x53c11f99'
    },
    {
      inputs: [Array],
      name: 'afterAgreementUpdated',
      outputs: [Array],
      stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
      type: 'function',
      constant: undefined,
      payable: undefined,
      signature: '0x230dbd29'
    },
    {
      inputs: [Array],
      name: 'beforeAgreementCreated',
      outputs: [Array],
      stateMutability: 'view',
      type: 'function',
      constant: true,
      payable: undefined,
      signature: '0x30d9c915'
    },
    {
      inputs: [Array],
      name: 'beforeAgreementTerminated',
      outputs: [Array],
      stateMutability: 'view',
      type: 'function',
      constant: true,
      payable: undefined,
      signature: '0x5f9e7d77'
    },
    {
      inputs: [Array],
      name: 'beforeAgreementUpdated',
      outputs: [Array],
      stateMutability: 'view',
      type: 'function',
      constant: true,
      payable: undefined,
      signature: '0x884d1f40'
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: 'currentReceiver',
      outputs: [Array],
      stateMutability: 'view',
      type: 'function',
      constant: true,
      payable: undefined,
      signature: '0x28d2bf94'
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: 'methodName',
      outputs: [Array],
      stateMutability: 'view',
      type: 'function',
      constant: true,
      payable: undefined,
      signature: '0x6d16b502'
    }
  ],
  address: '0x8ACEe021a27779d8E98B9650722676B850b25E11',
  transactionHash: '0x1562227e16df01cb4dcaa5f4a6d9df51315abef40ae60e68ac109a05a33b183f',
  contract: Contract {
    setProvider: [Function (anonymous)],
    currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
    _requestManager: RequestManager {
      provider: [HttpProvider],
      providers: [Object],
      subscriptions: Map(0) {}
    },
    givenProvider: null,
    providers: {
      WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
      HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
      IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider]
    },
    _provider: HttpProvider {
      withCredentials: false,
      timeout: 0,
      headers: undefined,
      agent: undefined,
      connected: true,
      host: 'http://127.0.0.1:37293/',
      httpAgent: [Agent],
      send: [Function (anonymous)],
      _alreadyWrapped: true
    },
    setRequestManager: [Function (anonymous)],
    BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
    extend: [Function: ex] {
      formatters: [Object],
      utils: [Object],
      Method: [Function: Method]
    },
    clearSubscriptions: [Function (anonymous)],
    options: { address: [Getter/Setter], jsonInterface: [Getter/Setter] },
    handleRevert: [Getter/Setter],
    defaultCommon: [Getter/Setter],
    defaultHardfork: [Getter/Setter],
    defaultChain: [Getter/Setter],
    transactionPollingTimeout: [Getter/Setter],
    transactionConfirmationBlocks: [Getter/Setter],
    transactionBlockTimeout: [Getter/Setter],
    defaultAccount: [Getter/Setter],
    defaultBlock: [Getter/Setter],
    methods: {
      afterAgreementCreated: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      '0xd86ed3e5': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      'afterAgreementCreated(address,address,bytes32,bytes,bytes,bytes)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      afterAgreementTerminated: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      '0x53c11f99': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      'afterAgreementTerminated(address,address,bytes32,bytes,bytes,bytes)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      afterAgreementUpdated: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      '0x230dbd29': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      'afterAgreementUpdated(address,address,bytes32,bytes,bytes,bytes)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      beforeAgreementCreated: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      '0x30d9c915': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      'beforeAgreementCreated(address,address,bytes32,bytes,bytes)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      beforeAgreementTerminated: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      '0x5f9e7d77': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      'beforeAgreementTerminated(address,address,bytes32,bytes,bytes)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      beforeAgreementUpdated: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      '0x884d1f40': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      'beforeAgreementUpdated(address,address,bytes32,bytes,bytes)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      currentReceiver: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      '0x28d2bf94': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      'currentReceiver()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      methodName: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      '0x6d16b502': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
      'methodName()': [Function: bound _createTxObject]
    },
    events: {
      ReceiverChanged: [Function: bound ],
      '0x7dfb1d59db37a3fd2e15e796c189dcab714cdbb18650d68a1de58f8fa60718c9': [Function: bound ],
      'ReceiverChanged(address)': [Function: bound ],
      allEvents: [Function: bound ]
    },
    _address: '0x8ACEe021a27779d8E98B9650722676B850b25E11',
    _jsonInterface: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ],
    transactionHash: '0x1562227e16df01cb4dcaa5f4a6d9df51315abef40ae60e68ac109a05a33b183f'
  },
  ReceiverChanged: [Function (anonymous)],
  afterAgreementCreated: [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  afterAgreementTerminated: [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  afterAgreementUpdated: [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  beforeAgreementCreated: [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  beforeAgreementTerminated: [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  beforeAgreementUpdated: [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  currentReceiver: [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  methodName: [Function (anonymous)] {
    call: [Function (anonymous)],
    sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
    request: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
  send: [Function (anonymous)],
  allEvents: [Function (anonymous)],
  getPastEvents: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Comment: What is the output from `pim`? Does it have an `address` property?

Comment: Good question. I made an edit to my original post. Of note, there's an _address and address value here in the console.log() statement but that gives me an error when I try calling pim.address or pim._address

Comment: I removed the `let` and it worked.